# AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime clash with applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: ios, notifications, avplayer, appdelegate

I've an `AVPlayer` embedded inside a `UIViewController`. I've added `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` notification to the `UIViewController` so that I can restart my `AVPlayer` once it finished playing `currentItem`

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object:player.currentItem)

    @objc private func playerDidFinishPlaying(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let url = URL(string: self.video.alt_content) else { return }

        let item = self.getAssetToPlay(url: url)
        item.seek(to: .zero, toleranceBefore: .zero, toleranceAfter: .zero)
        self.player.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)
        player.play()
    }

    private func getAssetToPlay(url: URL) -> AVPlayerItem {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
        let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        return item
    }
```

But this notification is also called from `AppDelegate's` `applicationDidBecomeActive`, like when my app comes from background. And so rather than playing `AVPlayer` from current time, code restarts the player in `playerDidFinishPlaying`.

I need a way so that when app comes from background it starts playing where it was left. And on completely finishing `currentItem`, it restarts the `AVPlayerItem`

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was very stupid to be honest. It was due to the fact that I added the `Observer` before initializing the `AVPlayer`. Once I corrected the code, it no longer clashes with `applicationDidBecomeActive`